# DeferredResult return blank page instead json

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-boot, jackson

I have rest controller in spring boot and when i return empty list or completefuture with result then response is json and it's correct, but I want to use DeferredResult(because non blocking io) and when I try return deferredresult with empty list then controller return nothing...

what's wrong?

```
@Async
@RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBodyDeferredResult<List<?>> test() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        final DeferredResult<List<?>> result = new DeferredResult<>();

        result.setResult(new ArrayList<>() );
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: `CompletableFuture` is also non-blocking, it will actually be wrapped in a `DeferredResult`. But you are doing nothing with the `DeferredResult` you will need to start a new `Thread` and when that completes set the result. You are currently returning directly without, eventually, setting the result.

Comment: Can you show me example with complatefuture ? I tried use this  but it' doesn't work
`public static <T> DeferredResult<T> from(final CompletableFuture<T> future) {
  final DeferredResult<T> deferred = new DeferredResult<>();
  future.thenAccept(deferred::setResult);
  future.exceptionally(ex -> {
   if (ex instanceof CompletionException) {
    deferred.setErrorResult(ex.getCause());
   } else {
    deferred.setErrorResult(ex);
   }
   return null;
  });
  return deferred;
 }`

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments with that much code. That makes it unreadable. You don't need to return a `DeferredResult` a `CompletableFuture` or `ListenableFuture` would do as well (or a `Callable` each will result in a non-blocking call). Also `@Async` is for something completely different don't use it on a controller method.

Comment: Also I should throw @Async and if I understood you,  CompletableFuture don't blocking i/o, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the controller method if you are using etags features in spring boot.

```
ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.disableContentCaching(request);
```